# getAccounts combined with infura.io does not return proper list of accounts

Tags: solidity, web3js

```
function metaMaskCh() {
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io"));
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result){ 
    if(error != null)
      console.log(error);
    else
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I've got at least two logged accounts, but using infura, I can not detect any of them:

[image]

Output of browser's console:

[image: output of browser's console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using metamask, you should stick with it:

```
web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

instead of

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io"));
```